# Create a singleton object scoped at the request level with out an IOC container

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

unfortunately I am working on a .Net 4 WebAPI project that is not using dependency injection, which means a lot of the information that comes through the HTTPContext is passed around as parameters which makes the method signature quite large an untidy.

If we were using an IOC container we could set some kind of HttpContextWrapper object to be constructed per request. Anyone know if this is possible without using a IOC container.

thanks
Todd

Comment: If it's scoped at the request level **by definition** it's not a singleton. I suspect there's a bit of confusion though. DI has nothing to do with the HttpContext, which shouldn't be used to pass data around anyway. Using a singleton HttpContext in Web API or MVC makes unit testing a lot harder, which is one reason it's no longer a singleton in ASP.NET Core

Comment: What does your code look like right now and why is it using HttpContext at all? Action parameters come from the clients, not HttpContext. When calling other methods, the easy, proper, clean way is to just pass the parameters, not store them in global variables. If one method has too many parameters, it probably means it does too much and should be broken. Or those parameters can be combined in a single parameter object. Whatever the problem is, it's not HttpContext

Comment: Your correct as singleton is not technically a per request scoped object and agreed shouldn't pass the httpContext around.

From the controller we grab a lot of parameters from Request.Headers, and pass these values to functions on other classes as parameters. What ia'm trying to do is wrap these values into a single object that is available for the lifetime of the request. Without using a DI container. And reduce the large method signatures

Comment: The HttpContext isn't the solution to that. For starters, you can use `FromHeader` to bind action parameters to headers. You can store the header values to a single strongly-typed object, or even a `Dictionary<string,string>`, and pass it to other methods. You can even generate that dictionary from the headers collection directly. Going through the HttpContext is the long way around and makes testing impossible

Comment: How are you expecting the methods can get the per-request parameters object? If you don't have DI, then constructor injection isn't possible. If you just pass the parameters object/a dictionary object around instead of passing a lot of parameters around, would that solve the problem? Or are you looking at accessing the ambient parameters using static class? Like `MyData.Current`.

Comment: Frankly, WebAPI has its own very basic dependency injection out of the box. Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/hh969144(v=vs.118)) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/hh969145(v=vs.118)). It's not that hard to put DI container in for the application then you would have more elegant solution. If I were to implement this, I would first look at DI. And only look for other options like ambient data possibly in a `AsyncLocal` if you are using async when DI is absolutely not possible.

Comment: @weichch DI is not an option at the moment unfortunately, You are correct I am looking for some sort of static class that set at a per request scope.

Answer (score 1):

*Replying based on DI isn't possible for the OP*

One possible solution is to borrow the implementation of [`HttpContextAccessor`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/8efcca43ceaaf72281e17f25d759844f488914ac/src/Http/Http/src/HttpContextAccessor.cs) from ASP.NET Core and set your request ambient data to [`AsyncLocal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.asynclocal-1?view=netframework-4.8) in a [DelegatingHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/http-message-handlers). In this way, your ambient data could be shared by methods within the scope of the request.

Here is what the ambient (per-request) data holder code should look like (not tested for production, use with caution):

```
public class AmbientData<T> where T : class
{
    private static readonly AsyncLocal<AmbientData<T>> CurrentData
        = new AsyncLocal<AmbientData<T>>();

    // Refer to HttpContextAccessor in ASP.NET Core
    public static T Current
    {
        get => CurrentData.Value?.Value;
        set
        {
            var currentData = CurrentData.Value;

            if (currentData != null)
            {
                currentData.Value = null;
            }

            if (value != null)
            {
                CurrentData.Value = new AmbientData<T> {Value = value};
            }
        }
    }

    private T Value { get; set; }
}

class MyData
{
    public int Value1 { get; set; }
    public string Value2 { get; set; }
}
```

Here is how ambient data set in request message handler:

```
public class AmbientDataRequestHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Set your request ambient data here, which then
        // sets it to AsyncLocal
        AmbientData<MyData>.Current = new MyData
        {
            Value1 = 123,
            Value2 = "xyz"
        };

        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

You need to add the request message handler to configuration in `WebApiConfig.cs`:

```
config.MessageHandlers.Add(new AmbientDataRequestHandler());
```

Then the data is available in your controller and all methods called within the scope of the request:

```
public IEnumerable<string> Get()
{
    // this is per-request scope
    var data = AmbientData<MyData>.Current;

    return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
}
```

Comment: Hi @weichch thanks for your help, and great solution. I should have clarified earlier thatr we are on .net 4.5.2., Unfortunately we are using AsyncLocal was only made available from 4.6 i believe.

Do you know of an alternative to to AsyncLocal.

thanks for all your help.

Comment: Depends on how you use async-await, you might be able to use `HttpContext.Current.Items` property. However, if you use `ConfigureAwait(false)` in some calls, `HttpContext.Current` can return `null`.